# Are there commonly used words to describe common pastries in Spain?

Tags: vocabulario, españa, comida

In English speaking countries, we tend to keep the French names for various types of pastries commonly eaten at breakfast: croissant, pain au chocolat, etc.

These don't seem to be used so much in Spain (though I recognise that most Spaniards would understand).

A blanket word for 'pastry' clearly exists, but that leaves one standing at a counter saying things like 'the square pastry on the second shelf with the chocolate sprinkles'.

In  my dictionary (Collins Spanish Dictionary Complete and Unabridged edition), there is a translation of croissant, but other types of pastry don't have entries. I've also noticed that many things *seem* to be referred to by some kind of shape description, for instance I've seen croissants referred to as 'shells'.

So my question is: **Are there commonly used words to describe common pastries in Spain (mainland, Madrid)?**

Comment: This is a list question, so it's technically off topic.  The reality is that these names change pretty heavily outside of a handful of super common ones (like a neopolitano, dónu(t), churros, or magdalena which are pretty universal).  It's quite common even for natives to point at something, describing it, ask what it's called in Spanish, buy it, enjoy it, and then promptly forget what it was called and have to ask again the next time they visit.

Comment: Is this for a project of some kind, or because you're feeling frustrated when you're at the bakery?

Comment: @aparente001 - frustrated at a bakery, never being able to order the tasty looking unusual things (british awkwardness, use the words you know and end up with something you didn't really want).

Comment: Is there a fellow customer who could help you?  Is there a slow time at the bakery, when you could ask one of the clerks to write down the names, or let you record them on your phone?  Could you convince a clerk to give you something different every day, and repeat the name several times?  I suppose you've already tried google images?  In Mexico, pastry has a generic name, *pan dulce*: "Disculpe, Ud. me podria ayudar a aprender los nombres de los diferentes tipos de pan dulce? (Sorry, my browser doesn't want to write accents today.)  An elderly person with time on his/her hands?

Comment: I am under the impression that we are going a bit far away in our laxity of allowing some kind of list questions. This is indeed an interesting topic but, as is now, goes beyond the scope of [se] and somehow enters in what could be an interesting blog entry or similar. I myself don't know some of these names in English and in cause of doubt I would check for that specific name if I asked in [ell.se] or [english.se]. So I would recommend to ask specific questions so we get specific answers. "List of bakery pastries" is too broad.

Comment: @fedorqui I suppose you are right, but I could not help writing an answer because, you know, pastries!! :-)

Comment: @Carlos Alejo I myself also love them and I find your answer very tasty and helpful :) Sharing knowledge is what we do here and is our main purpose. I think also that we need to put some little boundaries on what we accept, not to grow into some random status where things are difficult to find and classify. We have been discussing this with Diego (the other mod) and will talk about it in Meta soon. For the time being, I think some improvements on the question (_I have seen croissants and am not sure what their name in Spanish is, as well as X and Y_) could make it back on topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a whole lot of varieties of pastries in Spain, and most of them depends on the region. The other day one of my colleagues came to work with a load of *[perrunillas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perrunilla)* ([DLE definition](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SilQoKA)), a kind of almond pastries I did not know by that name. So I will try to add here the most common ones as I know them:

- [*Cruasán*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BMgxNEk) is the Spanish adaptation of *croissant*.
- [*Dónut*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dona_(comida)), also *dona, rosquilla*, is the common *doughnut*.
- [*Berlina*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlinesa), also *berlinesa, berlín* is how I know the filled, hole-less doughnut.
- [*Palmera*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palmera_(boller%C3%ADa)), you can find them in small, medium and [big sizes](http://www.diariosur.es/noticias/201508/11/media/kiki.nito.jpg). You can also find them covered with chocolate, a kind of yolk cream, and other toppings.
- [*Cuña de chocolate*](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-6uIrBXCFggw/VE479cRTHXI/AAAAAAAAFSM/WEUPj1wUa7Y/s1600/cu%C3%B1a%2B1.1.png), a cream-filled, chocolate-covered pastry.
- [*Caña de chocolate*](http://pasteleriatiamaria.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/5153-Ca%C3%B1a-de-chocolate-Pasteleria-Tia-Maria.png)/[*crema*](http://www.katyring.es/WebRoot/Store/Shops/katyring/4D71/0287/6A92/C05D/55EA/55EE/0960/A4C0/Cana_de_crema_artesanal.gif), a long, chocolate- or cream-filled pastry.
- [*Napolitana*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napolitana_(dulce)), similar to the *caña* but more rectangular-shaped.
- [*Sobao*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobao) or *sobao pasiego* is a speciality from Cantabria but very well known and appreciated in the whole country.
- You will find some differences between our traditional [*magdalenas*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magdalena_(alimento)) ([DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NsTgvgx)) and the imported *[muffins](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muffin)*, which we know by that name.
- [*Tarta*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZE4TQlp) is the generic name for cakes.
- And I suppose you know our [*churros*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Churro), because the word has been exported to many languages (including [Japanese](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%81%E3%83%A5%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B9)). There is also a variant known as *porras* (included in the Wikipedia entry for *churros*).

Other than that, I agree with guifa: most of the times we just point to the pastry we want, maybe describing it briefly.

Comment: I miss the _porras_! _Sobaos_ could also be a juicy addition.

Comment: +1. Añado el [*pepito*](http://www.carybe.es/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/pepito.variado-1.png) (éclair), [*buñuelo*](https://gastronomiaycia.republica.com/wp-content/photos/bunuelos_relle_crema3.jpg) (sweet fritter), [*hojaldre*](http://cdn1.cocina-familiar.com/recetas/pasteles-de-hojaldre-y-mermelada.jpg) (puff pastries), [*bizcocho*](https://www.hogarmania.com/archivos/201610/bizcocho-yogur-xl-848x477x80xX.jpg) (sponge cake), and my personal favorite: [*ensaimadas*](http://cdn.traveler.es/uploads/images/thumbs/201330/ia_la_rica_ensaimada_812_570x.jpg)

Comment: @fedorqui added! And just in time before you put the question on hold... :-)

Comment: You can edit a post anytime, no matter the question status!

Comment: @Yay Alas, I forgot the _ensaimadas_!!

Comment: Looks like you've got a lot of tasty stuff there.  But sadly no empanadas?